# python pafy youtube to mp3 error, KeyError: 'dislike_count'

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pafy

**this is my code it is very simple:**

```
import pafy
link = input("paste youtube link:  ")

video = pafy.new(link)
bestaudio = video.getbestaudio()
print(video.title)
bestaudio.download()
```

**and this is the error:**

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "c:\Users\neodi\Desktop\yt
> to mp3\input.py", line 4, in 
> video = pafy.new(link)   File "C:\Users\neodi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pafy\pafy.py",
> line 124, in new
> return Pafy(url, basic, gdata, size, callback, ydl_opts=ydl_opts)   File
> "C:\Users\neodi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pafy\backend_youtube_dl.py",
> line 31, in **init**
> super(YtdlPafy, self).**init**(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\neodi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pafy\backend_shared.py",
> line 97, in **init**
> self._fetch_basic()   File "C:\Users\neodi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pafy\backend_youtube_dl.py",
> line 54, in _fetch_basic
> self._dislikes = self._ydl_info['dislike_count'] KeyError: 'dislike_count'

**can anyone help?
and thank you if you do**

Comment: as I remember YouTube removed `dislike count` from webpage some time ago and it may need changes in `pafy` - so you may need to check if there is newer version (and update your module `pip install --update ...`), or you will have to wait for newer version.

Comment: it seems last version of [pafy](https://pypi.org/project/pafy/) is from 2019. You will have to use other module. ie. [youtube-dl](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl) or [pytube](https://pytube.io/en/latest/)

Comment: see also [KeyError: dislike\_count · Issue #306 · mps-youtube/pafy](https://github.com/mps-youtube/pafy/issues/306)

Answer (score 0):

Temporary fix:

> run `pip install -e git+git://github.com/mohamed-challal/pafy.git@develop#egg=pafy`
> or simply add `-e git+git://github.com/mohamed-challal/pafy.git@develop#egg=pafy` to your requirements.txt

Answer (score 0):

I commented the backend_youtube_dl.py file

line 53 and 54.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).